# Analyzing a PNP Transistor

Tags: transistors, pnp

I just wanted to confirm my calculations with someone. Here below is the question:
[image: PNP Transistor]

> So what I did was I found the voltage drop across V_E 
>   (which is equal to V_EE minus the constant V_E) 
>   which was 15V - .04V, which then I was able to find 
>   current I_E = 14.6V/1.5E3 = 0.0097 amperes.

Then

> I did the same with the voltage drop across V_B = V_in - V_B (4-.6) = 3.4V.
>   I then used the equation I_B = I_E/(1+B) (B is 200 (beta) in the figure.)
>   I got  0.0097A/(1+200) = 4.84E-5 amperes.

Finally

> I used Ohms law to rearrange to find R_B = V_B/I_B = 3.4/4.84E-5 = 70212.3 Ω.

Comment: Are you sure about the details in this question?  Vo cannot be 0.4V for Vin = 4V. Vo will be somewhere between 4.7V and 15V, depending on Rb. Assuming Rb >= 0, of course.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany, you’re right. Also this circuit doesn’t make sense being used like this. Using PNP as switch would need to have 1.5k between collector and ground. Or if this was NPN then it would work when Rb is connected to base and emitter is grounded.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany A negative static resistance is indeed rare. But see ***Chua, L., Juebang Yu, & Youying Yu, 1985, "Bipolar - JFET - MOSFET Negative Resistance Devices," IEEE Transactions on Circuits and Systems, 32(1), 46–61. doi:10.1109/tcs.1985.1085599*** for those moments when you need a junkbox *passive* negative dynamic resistance and *that* Esaki diode just seems too elusive. (It's actually a nice paper.)

Comment: @jonk Interesting. A wide range of thyristor-like circuits.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany What made me happier about it was the inclusion of the Esaki (type-N in the paper) behaviors in Section II.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: 
I believe you mistakenly used a PNP in your schematic instead of an NPN. The way it is now, wouldn’t work to give you V_o of 0.4V. If you were using NPN with base resistor connect to base, emitter grounded, and 1.5k connected between supply and collector then it would work with your calculations.